# Add value of selected radio button to user input sum

Tags: jquery, function, calculator, onchange

I have created a basic calculator that adds 24% to the number that the user types in.

I am trying to add in a second step where the user selects a radio button and this also gets added on to the total of the number generated. I have started writing an on change event, but I'm not sure that this is the best way to do it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var biddingFee;
  var $lotValue = $("#lotValue"),
    $bid = $("#totalBid"),

    $buyersPremium = $("#buyersPremium"),
    $liveBiddingFee = $("#liveBiddingFee")


  $('input[type=radio][name=group1]').change(function() {
    if (this.value == '0') {
      biddingFee = 0;
    } else if (this.value == '3') {
      biddingFee = 3;
    } else if (this.value == '5') {
      biddingFee = 5;
    } else if (this.value == '6') {
      biddingFee = 6;
    }
  });

  $lotValue.keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      return;
    }

    var lotValue = parseFloat($lotValue.val()),
      bid = lotValue * 0.24;

    if (isNaN(bid) || isNaN(lotValue)) {
      $bid.hide();
      return;
    }

    var bidValue = lotValue + bid;

    $('.line').hide();

    $buyersPremium.fadeIn().find(".buyersPremiumNumber").text((bid).toFixed(2));

    $bid.fadeIn().find(".totalBidNumber").text((bidValue).toFixed(2));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>1. Enter your bid: <input name="lotValue" id="lotValue" type="number" class="form-control" /></p>

<p id="buyersPremium">The Buyers Premium (inc VAT) is £<span class="buyersPremiumNumber"></span></p>

<br>

<div class="biddingMethods">
  <p>2. Choose a live bidding method.</p>
  <label><input type="radio" name="group1" value="0" checked>Type 1 (£0)</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="group1" value="3">Type 2 (£3)</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="group1" value="5">Type 3 (£5)</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="group1" value="6">Type 4 (£6)</label>

  <p id="liveBiddingFee">The Live Bidding Fee is £<span id="price"></span></p>
</div>

<br>

<p id="totalBid">Total £<span class="totalBidNumber"></span></p>
```

Working jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/devful_rs14/wa7xcns4/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you require, the simplest, most accurate, most maintainable and most extensible method is to have a single function which retrieves all the required values from the DOM when any of the DOM elements involved in the calculation is updated. This avoids the need for ugly global variables, and keeps the logic contained in a single place.

In addition to the above, note that you should be using the `input` event to listen for textbox changes, not keyup, as the former also fires when content is pasted in using the mouse. In addition you can apply a common `class` attribute to the radio inputs to make selecting them more succinct.

Lastly, note the use of `toLocaleString()` instead of `.toFixed(2)` when displaying the currency value. This will avoid rounding errors, and also format the numeric value in to a regional currency string. It will also allow you to easily tailor the UI to the user's region, if necessary. I've just hard-coded it to `en-GB` for this example though, to follow the example in the question.

With all that said, here's a working example:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let biddingFee;
  let buyersPremiumFactor = 0.24;
  let locale = 'en-GB'
  let currencyLocaleSettings = { style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP' };

  let $lotValue = $("#lotValue");
  let $buyersPremium = $("#buyersPremium");
  let $bid = $("#totalBid");
  let $biddingMethods = $('.biddingMethod');
  let $liveBiddingFee = $("#liveBiddingFee");
    
  let calculateBidTotal = () => {
    let bidValue = parseFloat($lotValue.val()) || 0; // coerce value to zero if non-numeric
    let buyersPremiumValue = bidValue * buyersPremiumFactor; 
    let biddingMethodValue = parseInt($biddingMethods.filter(':checked').val(), 10);
    let totalBidCost = bidValue + buyersPremiumValue + biddingMethodValue;

    $buyersPremium.fadeIn().find(".buyersPremiumNumber").text(buyersPremiumValue.toLocaleString(locale, currencyLocaleSettings));
    $liveBiddingFee.fadeIn().find("#price").text(biddingMethodValue.toLocaleString(locale, currencyLocaleSettings));
    $bid.fadeIn().find(".totalBidNumber").text(totalBidCost.toLocaleString(locale, currencyLocaleSettings));
  }

  $biddingMethods.on('change', calculateBidTotal)
  $lotValue.on('input', calculateBidTotal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  1. Enter your bid: 
  <input name="lotValue" id="lotValue" type="number" class="form-control" />
</p>
<p id="buyersPremium">
  The Buyers Premium (inc VAT) is <span class="buyersPremiumNumber"></span>
</p>
<br />

<div class="biddingMethods">
  <p>2. Choose a live bidding method.</p>
  <label><input type="radio" class="biddingMethod" name="group1" value="0" checked>Type 1 (£0)</label>
  <label><input type="radio" class="biddingMethod" name="group1" value="3">Type 2 (£3)</label>
  <label><input type="radio" class="biddingMethod" name="group1" value="5">Type 3 (£5)</label>
  <label><input type="radio" class="biddingMethod" name="group1" value="6">Type 4 (£6)</label>
  <p id="liveBiddingFee">The Live Bidding Fee is <span id="price"></span></p>
</div>
<br>

<p id="totalBid">
  Total <span class="totalBidNumber"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. Could this be modified to include both numbers and percentages as the radio button values instead? For example Type 2 could be £3, but Type 3 could be 5%?

Comment: Sure, change the value to the factor, `0.05` in this case, and add a class on to the radios which you can detect to determine whether the values need to be added or multiplied.

Comment: I seem to be unable to get this to work. I have added in an if statement and a class on the radio buttons that should be percentages. The £0 and £3 options work fine, but the percentages return 0. I have created a new jsfiddle demonstrating this https://jsfiddle.net/devful_rs14/fm2xspc6/4/

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/g5frwx2j/

Comment: That's great, thanks so much. Makes much more sense than what I was attempting.